# Ends of plot get cut off

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

About 1/10 of one of my plots gets cut off on both sides, no matter how `xmin` and `xmax` are set. How can this be prevented?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture} \pgfplotsset{scale only axis}
        \begin{axis}[ymin=0,xmin=0,xmax=1,
        axis y line*=left,
        width=13cm,height=7cm,tick align=center]
        \addplot[smooth]
        coordinates{
            (0.0001,2)
            (0.999999,2)    
        };  
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,width=13cm,height=7cm]

        \addplot[dotted]
        coordinates{
            (0.0001, 1)
            (0.99999,1)};   
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to give, xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax to the second `axis` environment too. But I am not sure what you really want to do.

Comment: If you replace `\pgfplotsset{scale only axis}` by `\pgfplotsset{scale only axis,xmin=0,xmax=1}` then these values will apply to all plots in this `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Both approaches managed to solve my problem. Thanks.